# CSS class changing on the console but not reflected on the DOM (flask proejct)

Tags: javascript, css, flask, dom, rendering

I'm building a web app with Flask and I'm trying to build a small dropdown menu for logging the user out. I added an event listener to the nav bar (either mobile or desktop) and the code works well as reflected on the console (I'm console logging the element and the target as you can see), but this change doesn't reflect on the DOM.
If I add the class manually to the DOM it does. I've tried adding the event listener to other elements too but nothing seems to work.
I've also tried to use other CSS arrangements to change the specificity, but the result is the same.
I mentioned that I'm using Flask in case Jinja is messing up with this since this is the main layout html that every template is inheriting from.
Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="mobile-user">
        <div class="user-menu">
            <img class="profile-img" src="../static/assets/user.png" alt="user's photo">
            <div id="logout" class="logout">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
//...irrelevant html between these two
       <nav class="desktop-nav">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><h2>queerevent</h2></a>
            </div>
            {% if not current_user.is_anonymous %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/favorites">Favorites</a></li>
                <li><a href="/my-events">My Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/calendar">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="/new">New Event</a></li>
                <li class="user-menu">
                    <img class="profile-img" id="user-img" src="../static/assets/user.png" alt="user's image">
                    <div id="logout" class="logout">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="{{ url_for('account') }}">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
#logout {
    position: relative;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 1.5rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.logout {
    display: none;
}

.logout.active {
    display: inline-block;
}

#logout::before {
    content: '▲';
    position: absolute;
    top: -25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```
'use strict'
const menu = document.querySelector('.desktop-nav') || document.querySelector('.mobile-user')

menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const userImage = document.querySelector('#user-img')
    const logoutMenu = document.querySelector('.logout');
    console.log(e.target)
    if (e.target === userImage) {
        logoutMenu.classList.toggle('active');
        console.log(logoutMenu)
    }
})
```

Comment: I just want to know why you don't attach click listener to #user-img ?

Comment: It was the first thing I did but in that case the event listener wouldn't even get added. I opened the console and the variable was there but the event listener wasn't added. So I tried with the parent and it worked. The event is ocurring and the class is been toggled, but the DOM doesn't change

Comment: I guess you add the event after the DOM finishes loading, right?

Comment: Yes, the script is at the end of the body

Comment: If you use Chrome and after you see `console.log(logoutMenu)`, you can double click on the element in the console, you'll see its class updated. If it was updated, you see `active`, but don't see the element visible on the screen, you may want to inspect that element to see what's CSS property is not correct.

Comment: The element has the class active toggled in the console but it doesn't change on the DOM. But if I add it manually in the inspector everything works

Comment: It's quite hard to know what problem is :( Can you make a snippet right in here? 
But I just guess it may be the order of classes...

Comment: This is what I get in the console when I click
```
<img id="user-img" class="profile-img" src="../static/assets/user.png" alt="user's image">
layout.js:7:13
<div id="logout" class="logout active">
layout.js:10:17
<img id="user-img" class="profile-img" src="../static/assets/user.png" alt="user's image">
layout.js:7:13
<div id="logout" class="logout">
layout.js:10:17
<img id="user-img" class="profile-img" src="../static/assets/user.png" alt="user's image">
layout.js:7:13
<div id="logout" class="logout active">

```

Comment: Sorry for the mess, it's not recognizing the md down here. You think I should put the active class higher?

Comment: Hmm. It should be correct with those classes. Can you check its CSS properties? If you haven't tried it yet, you can follow this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css). An overridden property will be stricken through. And you should check if your logout element is in the correct position or not.

Comment: I've changed the display for better accesibility and put the logout menu out of the page and then when active back in but the result is the same. The JS is working correctly and the CSS too. The class gets toggled and if I add it mannually in the inspector everything works fine. But the JS is not reflecting on the DOM

Comment: I've also tried to put it out of the <li> and other arrangements. I've tried other browsers too

Comment: If you're still working on it and don't mind sharing the code on Github, I can help. I'm just afraid, the problem is not visible in codes above.

Comment: I deleted it and just added the logout option to a page :( But thank you so much for your time and effort!